# Why forkJoin does not emit value?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is a load$ subject that triggers two stream. After these streams forked into one:

```
this.sourceWithImage$ = this.load$.pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    of(1).pipe(
      delay(3000),
      map(() => new Date().getMilliseconds())
    )
  )
);

this.sourceWithFields$ = this.load$.pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    of(2).pipe(
      delay(2000),
      map(() => new Date().getMilliseconds())
    )
  )
);

this.sourceData$ = this.load$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => forkJoin([this.sourceWithImage$, this.sourceWithFields$]))
);

this.sourceData$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
```

Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-rgiklz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Why forkJoin does not emit value?

I need to load two streams in parallel

Comment: If an inner observable does not complete forkJoin will never emit a value!

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

It's also worth noting that if you have an observable that emits more than one item, and you are concerned with the previous emissions forkJoin is not the correct choice. In these cases you may be better off with an operator like

Comment: Like what? Why forkJoin does not work if I use take(1) for each stream?

Comment: Also your `sourceData$` is dependent on `load$` which is switchMapped with `sourceWithImage$` and `sourceWithFields$` which is also dependent on `load$`.

The flow is wrong.

loadData -> sourceData -> expects loadData to trigger again.

Comment: better operators like `combineLatest`

Comment: Yes, because I need to add an image and fields to initial data. But load then in parallel

Comment: combineLatest also not working:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-rgiklz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forkJoin` can only emit a value when all inputs have finished.

[ForkJoin docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin#description)

> **Wait for Observables to complete** and then combine last values they emitted; complete immediately if an empty array is passed

So you may want to use `take(1)` or change your logic, like this
[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wpb3vl?file=index.html,index.ts)

```js
const load$ = new Subject();

const sourceWithImage$ = of(1).pipe(
  delay(3000),
  map(() => new Date().getMilliseconds())
);

const sourceWithFields$ = of(2).pipe(
  delay(2000),
  map(() => new Date().getMilliseconds())
);

const sourceData$ = load$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => forkJoin([sourceWithImage$, sourceWithFields$]))
);

sourceData$.subscribe({
  next: (v) => console.log(v),
  error: (e) => console.log(e),
});
load$.next(1);
```

Comment: I did not get why it is working, because you dont use take(1) to finish streams in forkJoin

Comment: I need to inhance initial data by image and fields. But load it in parallel to improve performance. Then return a result stream with initial data + image + fields.

Comment: The sourceWithImage$ shoud get image url from initial source the load it,

Comment: `of(1)` will emit `1` and then complete - so there is no need for `take(1)`